Declared height and depth of operators ignored by unicode engines?
It started with \lowint and \upint of unicode-math trying to place the limits "propely". "Properly" means they should not be placed at the height and depth of \lowint and \upint because they look as negated. So if you use $\lowint_a$ the a is placed in front of the bar and looks as -a. The correct placement is to place the limits at the same height and depth as the \int operator. How can one do that?
From the font side the Math Table supports the explicit declaration of the height and depth of operators. So one can give for \lowint and \upint the same height and depth as \int
But alas, xelatex and lualatex ignore this parameter and use the true height and depth of \lowint and \upint.
This is a continuation of Lower and upper Riemann integrals?
Here is a minimal example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmathfont{GFSNeohellenicMath.otf}
\begin{document}
$$\lowint_a^b \quad\int_a^b\quad \upint_a^b$$
\end{document}

This gives

Notice that upper b appears as -b (last integral) and lower a as -a (first integral). Moreover, the integrals have erratic vertical alignment. It would be correct if all the integral signs align and lowbar and upper bar extent to the bottom or top.
For this font the bars can not be replaced by a \rule (so one could use a macro) as they are not straight and match the design.

You provide no code and reference a question that has 6 different answers, it makes it very hard to guess what you have done or what change you want. Please include a complete document that shows the problem and describe what change you want

I can offer a font specific adjustment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmathfont{GFSNeohellenicMath.otf}
%\setmathfont{New Computer Modern Math}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy{\lowint@}{\lowint}%
  \NewCommandCopy{\upint@}{\upint}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\lowint}{\lowint@@}%
  \RenewCommandCopy{\upint}{\upint@@}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lowint@@}{e{_^}}{\mathop{\mathpalette\lowint@@@{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\lowint@@@}[2]{\lowint@@@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\lowint@@@@}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\int$}%
  \raisebox{-\ifx#1\displaystyle0.18\else0.36\fi\dp\z@}{%
    $\m@th#1\lowint@
    \IfValueT{#2}{_{\raisebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle0.35\else0.7\fi\dp\z@}{$\m@th\scriptstyle#2$}}}%
    \IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}$%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\upint@@}{e{_^}}{\mathop{\mathpalette\upint@@@{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\upint@@@}[2]{\upint@@@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\upint@@@@}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\int$}%
  \raisebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle0.16\else0.32\fi\dp\z@}{%
    $\m@th#1\upint@
    \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}%
    \IfValueT{#3}{^{\raisebox{-\ifx#1\displaystyle0.33\else0.66\fi\dp\z@}{$\m@th\scriptstyle#3$}}}$%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\guide{\makebox[0pt]{\vrule depth0.1pt height 0pt width 3cm}}

\begin{document}

\[
\sbox0{$\displaystyle\int$}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\vrule depth \dimeval{\dp0+0.1pt} height -\dp0 width 3cm}%
\lowint_a^b \quad\int_{a\guide}^{b\guide}\quad \upint_a^b
\]
\begin{center}
\sbox0{$\int$}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\vrule depth \dimeval{\dp0+0.1pt} height -\dp0 width 3cm}%
$\lowint_a^b \quad\int_{a\guide}^{b\guide}\quad \upint_a^b$
\end{center}

\end{document}

\guide and the \makebox commands only provide guide rules.

However, the values don't quite work for NewComputerModern Math:


Wow! this is quite non trivial. Thank you. I guess I can copy your code in fontsetup for these fonts, right? On the other hand it shows that unicode-math/fontspec do not handle this properly. For example, MathTable supports lowering and raising the limits (as well as kern them) but these parameters of the font are ignored too by tex engines. I guess I should report this to Will. In any case with your code at least we have a solution.

@Antonis I believe that something can be done with LuaMetaTeX, which adds many more features for math symbols. With the current LuaTeX or XeLaTeX there's no hope.

What is LuaMetaTeX? never heard of...

@Antonis It's the successor engine to LuaTeX, currently only used by ConTeXt (and developed by the same people)

I can show similar approach, but horizontal measuring and shifting the subscript left is done here.
The macros are written in OpTeX, you can compare the macro programming in both answers.
\fontfam[xits]

\let\lowintori=\lowint  \let\upintori=\upint
\protected\def\mylowint{{\lowintori}{\vphantom{\int}}\isnextchar _{\mylowintA}{}}
\protected\def\myupint {{\upintori}{\vphantom{\int}}\isnextchar _{\mylowintA}{}}
\def\mylowintA _#1{\setmathstyle
   \setbox0=\hbox{$\usemathstyle\lowint_x$}\setbox1=\hbox{$\usemathstyle\lowint^x$}
   \tmpdim=\wd0 \advance\tmpdim by-\wd1
   _{\kern\tmpdim#1}}

%% uncomment this if you want to use changed \lowint, \upint:
% \let\upint=\myupint  \let\lowint=\mylowint 

Tests:
$$
   \int_a^b f, \quad \mylowint_a^b f, \quad \myupint_a^b f, \quad 
   \lowint_a^b f, \quad \upint_a^b f
$$
$\mylowint_a^b$, $\myupint_a^b, \lowint_a^b, \upint_a^b$

\bye

